# Orchard CMS - Difference between Layer & Content Type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm adding a 'contact form' page to an Orchard site (that I'm making to learn Orchard).

First I added it as a layer. Then I found out you can add it as a Content Type.

I find this all very confusing.

What is the difference & relationship between layers, content types, modules & widgets. And why are there no pages?!

Why is TripelFirst a layer for example - not a widget?

Why can't I just make a 'contact' page and add a widget to it called 'Contact Form'?!

What's the difference between modules & widgets - they sound like the same thing.

What would be the best practice way to add a Contact Us page - as a layer or a Content Type?

Thanks.

Comment: For the record I abandoned Orchard it's WAY too complex. Switched to C1 CMS, it's a dream to use and it is free it's only certain power features they charge for, which I've never needed to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
What is the difference & relationship between layers, content types, 
modules & widgets. And why are there no pages?!
```

**Layers** control which widgets appear in which *zones* (designated by the theme) on a particular page. They have rules, so for example, I could have a layer called *NotHomePage* and give it the rule **not url("~/")** and any widgets added to *zones* on that layer would appear everywhere but the home page.

**Content types** are just that--types of the content you create on the site. A *Page* is a content type you get out of the box with Orchard. It contains a part called *Route* so one of the first properties you have the option of creating is the slug e.g. mydomain.com/**sweet-page**.

**Modules** are basically MVC areas that create specific functionality for a website. A module may contain some custom parts, some script, some styling, etc. There are a couple contact form *modules* out there, but you'd probably learn more if you used the **Custom Forms** module that is already cooked in the default Orchard recipe (I think you have to enable it, but it's there.)

**Widgets** are like code snippets you add to *zones* (designated by the theme) on a layer where you can have as many widgets as you like. Maybe your home page has a "MainContent" zone where your customer would like to have their tagLine and a small form to sign up for a newsletter. You could add an HTML widget for the tagline (which contains basic information like a WYSIWYG editor for the HTML) and a Custom Form widget (which will handle creating s sign up request.)

```
Why is TripelFirst a layer for example - not a widget?
```

TripelFirst should not be a layer, it should be a *zone* in the TheThemeMachine theme i.e. an area on the page that may or may not contain widgets.

```
Why can't I just make a 'contact' page and add a widget 
to it called 'Contact Form'?!
```

You can, but you would need to define a couple things first.

1. Create a content type called ContactFormRequest (you might need to enable 'Content Types' module)
2. Add fields (first name, last name, etc) like you would add properties to a class definition
3. Create a page called **Contact** with the slug **/contact**
4. Create a layer called **ContactLayer** with the rule **url("/contact")**
5. Add a Custom Form widget to ContactLayer and be sure to select *ContactFormRequest* as the content type
6. party

This should give you the basic behavior you're looking for. You can, of course, customize this further.

```
What would be the best practice way to add a Contact Us page - 
as a layer or a Content Type?
```

Personally, I prefer the flexibility of using my own content type e.g. ContactFormRequest. If, in the future, my customer wants to add height, weight and age as properties to the contact form, I have only to add these fields to the content type and Orchard handles the rest.

Comment: Thanks - that's helped a bit - I think it's just a lot to learn. Having some inline help in the back end would be really helpful for remembering this (maybe have a 'learning mode' or something).

Comment: interesting idea--we could technically write a module for that!